# How to compute $[\dot c, X]$ on a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, smooth-manifolds, curves, lie-derivative

Consider a smooth curve $c : [0,1] \to M$ and $X \in \mathcal X (M)$. How can one obtain an explicit formula for $[\dot c, X]$?

I know the theoretical approach: for every $t \in [0,1]$ there exist a neighbourhood $U_t$ of $c(t)$ and a local tangent field $C_t \in \mathcal X (U_t)$ that extends $\dot c$, so one computes $[C_t, X]$ and then evaluates it at $c(t)$.

Theory is nice, but putting it into practice does not look obvious; how should I do it? Concretely, the problem is that in local coordinates and choosing $X = \partial _i$ I would obtain $- \sum \limits _j (\partial _i C_t ^j) \partial _j$. How would I evaluate $\partial _i C_t ^j$ in $c(t)$? In other words, how do I compute $\partial _i \dot c ^j$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly: what do you expect in the case $M=\mathbb{R}^2$, $c(t)=(t,0)$ and $X=\partial_2$? there are many ways to extend $\dot c$, e.g., for any smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $C(x,y)=\partial_1+g(y)\partial_2$. Then $[C,X]_{c(t)}=-g'(0)\partial_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lie bracket $[\dot c,X]$ is not well defined. A Lie bracket requires two *vector fields* defined on an open set, so as you noted, to make sense of this bracket you need to extend $\dot c$ to a vector field. But different extensions will give different results.

For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, suppose $c(t) = (t,0)$ and $X(x,y) = \partial/\partial y$. Then $V_1(x,y) = \partial/\partial x$ and $V_2(x,y) = (1+y)\partial/\partial x$ are both extensions of $\dot c$, but $[V_1,X] = 0$ while $[V_2,X] = - \partial/\partial x$.

Comment: I understand, thank you. What is interesting is that expressions such as $\nabla _{\dot c} {\dot c}$, or $\nabla _{\dot c} T$ where $T$ is a tensor field, or $\nabla _v T$ where $v \in T_x M$ do make sense. Is it possible to tell at first sight those such expressions that make sense from those which don't?

Comment: In Koszul's formula for the Levi-Civita connection $2 g(\nabla _X Y, Z) = R.H.S.$ (where my question stems from), if one takes $X = Y = \dot c$, then the R.H.S. will contain, among others, terms such as $g([\dot c, Z], \dot c)$. Should I understand that these individual terms do not make sense, and only their sum with the remaining ones does? Or that the Lie bracket does not, but its scalar product with $\dot c$ does?

Comment: If $X,Y$ are vector fields and $\nabla$ is a connection, it follows from properties of vector fields that the value of $\nabla_X Y$ at a point $p$ depends only on the value of $X$ at $p$ and the values of $Y$ along any curve whose velocity at $p$ is equal to $X_p$. (See my _Riemannian Manifolds_, ch. 4.) Thus $\nabla_{\dot c}{\dot c}$ and $\nabla_{\dot c} T$ are independent of the extension chosen for $\dot c$. In Koszul's formula, you have to choose extensions for $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ to do the computation, and individual terms will depend on the extensions; but the final value will not.